# How to open blank html page when button is pressed on android

Tags: android, html, button, android-activity, onclick

So I've gone through the basic tutorial and I've read up on activities and UI listeners.

However I'm still unsure on how to open an HTML page when I select a button.

What I think I have to do is, make an HTML file and store it in the res/layout folder, create an activity which is connected to the HTML file.  Then I'm not sure what to do.  Where do I call the `OnClickListener` function and when do I handle the event of the button being clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should consider starting with something simpler, as an apparent newcomer to Android.

Be that as it may...

First, you need to decide where the "HTML page" is: on the phone, or on the Internet. For right now, the correct answer is "on the Internet". You will need the URL for it (e.g., `http://www.ohai.com/kthxbye.html`).

Then, you need to create a layout file, in the `res/layout/` folder, containing your `Button`. This is not an HTML file -- it is an Android layout file. Assuming you are going to run on Android 1.6 and newer devices, you can add an attribute to the `<Button>` element, named `android:onClick`, that will name a method in your soon-to-be-written `Activity` class. If you are just working with a new project, you might as well just modify the `res/layout/main.xml` file that is supplied to you to have this `Button`.

Then, you need to create an `Activity` class. Your project hopefully already has an `Activity` class set up for you; if not, you will need to create one yourself. In `onCreate()`, use `setContentView(R.layout.main)` (or whatever) to load up the layout file.

Add a method, of the name you specified in `android:onClick`, to your `Activity`, returning `void` and taking a `View` as a parameter. In there, add in a line like:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Uri.parse("...")));
```

where `...` is replaced with the URL to your HTML file.

Now, it is possible to have the HTML baked into your application, but then you will have a fair bit of difficulty getting the browser application to view it, since that application has no right to your application's files. There are a few ways to deal with that, all of which are relatively complicated.

Comment: Thanks, this makes alot of sense its way easier than I was expecting it to be. However by using the code that you suggested I received an error: for: void codeBtn = startActivity(new Intent(this, Uri.parse("spu.edu";))); It says that codeBtn cannot be type void. What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: @Conner: Don't attempt to assign the result of `startActivity()` to anything. If you are new to Java, you should spend some time learning Java outside of Android, as most of the Java educational materials will be aimed at desktop/server development. Here is a blog post with a list of topics to learn: http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/02/java-good-parts-version.html